# If a cohen's wife has an affair with a non-Jew after they are married do they have to get divorced?

Tags: marriage, kohen-priest

I know that someone is considered a zona if they have had forbidden relations including with non-Jews and those in their family but what if this were found to happen whilst they are already married so do they have to get divorced?

Comment: You include two questions, Wife and Cohen Wife. Cohen wife has two problems. EG in a case of rape, when an Israel wife isn't prohibited, a Cohen wife is. For a Cohen, there is a prohibition called Zona. A forbided relationship or a relationship with a Pasul, even if permitted makes her a Zona.

Comment: אשת כהן שבויה אסורה לבעלה

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. Always ask a rabbi about practical cases, but as a general rule, even if it was before they were married they would have to get divorced.

Answer (score 1):

We'll add sources later, but the answer is certainly yes. Any married Jewish woman who willingly sleeps with another man (Jewish or otherwise) needs to get divorced, and a kohen's wife has to do so even if she's raped, God forbid.